# Server (ng serve) cannot be started in angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-template

I am new to angular 2. For last two days it was working good but when I came to start the angular 2 project locally by typing ng serve in command prompt it is not working. It throws the following error,
`

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.8
3 info using node@v6.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle demo@0.0.0~prestart: demo@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle demo@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle demo@0.0.0~start: demo@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle demo@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle demo@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\msuman\Desktop\work14th\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\msuman\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle demo@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\msuman\Desktop\work14th
11 silly lifecycle demo@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng serve' ]
12 silly lifecycle demo@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle demo@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: demo@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid demo@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\msuman\Desktop\work14th
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7600
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.9.0
20 error npm  v3.10.8
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error demo@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the demo@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the demo package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ng serve
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs demo
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls demo
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

`

Here is the screenshot of command prompt error,

[image]

[image]
I tried everything but can't make it done.
Will you please help me doing this?

Thanks in advance.

here is the content of angular-cli

`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "demo"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css",
        "../node_modules/ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
        "../src/assets/js/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/ion-rangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/slider.js",
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js",

      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Could you try an `npm install` before ng serve ? you should have no errors in your npm install

Comment: @trichetriche yes I have done it. Still showing the same error.

Comment: Could you post the end of the log of your npm install  ?

Comment: @trichetriche PLEASE check the screenshots I attached now in desc.

Comment: It says you have an error in your angular-cli.json file, could you post its content please ?

Comment: @trichetriche please check now.

Comment: @trichetriche again having the same problem, while I have corrected the angular.ci.json page.

Comment: Make a new post for it then, this one is over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is withing the `scripts` key inside the JSON since JSON specification doesn't allow a trailing comma.

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/ion-rangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js",
    "../src/assets/js/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.js",
    "../src/assets/js/slider.js",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js",

]
```

Simply remove the blank line together with the comma at the end of the line just like in the snippet below.

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/ion-rangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js",
    "../src/assets/js/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.js",
    "../src/assets/js/slider.js",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
]
```

Comment: please let me try.

Comment: Damn, I just went away to grab something to eat, and came back to the answer :(